# Unable to access deployed Angular application on Google cloud

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have developed my project on Google cloud using Nodejs,Angular, MongoDB and Express. I have successfully built the Authentication part for Express and Node.js. Now I am trying to integrate Angular. I have setup Ingress-NGINX using Google cloud and am utilizing Google cloud shell to create the code.

I followed the steps below for setup

Steps for setting up Ingress-NGINX on Google Cloud

1. Create a project blog-dev
2. Create cluster blog-dev with 3 N1-g1 small instances in us-central1-c zone
3. Navigate to https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke
4. On the Google cloud account, open the cloud shell and navigate to BPB_MEAN_Framework directory in terminal
5. Execute the command
   gcloud init, reinitialize the cluster, select the account, project and the region
6. Execute the command gcloud container clusters get-credentials blog-dev
7. Execute the command kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.0.3/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml to configure ingress-nginx
8. Go to Network Services -> Load Balancing and check that the Load Balancer has got created. Note the ip of the Load Balancer
9. Open the hosts.ini file and update as shown below
   130.211.113.34 blog.dev
   8.1)
   kubectl create secret generic jwt-secret --from-literal=JWT_KEY=asdf
10. Run scaffold dev
11. Go to http://blog.dev/api/users/currentuser in a browser and get the 'Privacy Error' page. Click 'Advanced' here
12. Type thisisunsafe on keyboard

The various files are listed below

Listed below is the Kubernetes deployment yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: client-depl
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client 
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: us.gcr.io/blog-dev-326403/client:project-latest
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: client
  ports: 
    - name: client
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4200
      targetPort: 4200
```

Listed below is the Ingress service

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: blog.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: auth-srv
              servicePort: 3100
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: client-srv
              servicePort: 4200
```

Listed below is the Skaffold yaml

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl: 
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  #local:
   # push: false
  googleCloudBuild:
    projectId: blog-dev-326403
  artifacts:
    - image: us.gcr.io/blog-dev-326403/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/.ts'
            dest: .
    - image: us.gcr.io/blog-dev-326403/client
      context: client
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/.ts'
            dest: .
```

The angular folder structure is shown below
[Angular project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkRAW.png)

I added the Google cloud Load Balancer ip followed by blog.dev in hosts.ini file.

When I run skaffold dev, there are no errors. When I try to access blog.dev, I get a 502 bad gateway.

When I navigate to client directory and type npm start and access preview in Google cloud shell, I get my website as shown
[Application in preview mode in Google cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVTe9.png)
Please help...This is a showstopper for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer myself. Here is my solution

Package.json

The package.json entry is given below

```
"prod": "ng build --prod",
```

Angular Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.4.0 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run prod

FROM nginx:1.19
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /app/dist/Angular-Mean/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I put an nginx configuration file as below

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript 
    application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss 
    text/javascript;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  }
```

}

The deployment file is shown below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: client-depl
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client 
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: us.gcr.io/blog-dev-326403/client:project-latest
          ports:
          - containerPort: 4200
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: client
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports: 
    - name: client
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31000
```

The final artifact is ingress service

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: blog.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: auth-srv
              servicePort: 3100
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: client-srv
              servicePort: 80
```

Rest of the configuration remains same. Please use this configuration and navigate to https://blog.dev and you get the output as shown[Blog Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwvb5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the container port from deployment

```
ports:
- containerPort: 80
```

deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: client-depl
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client 
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: us.gcr.io/blog-dev-326403/client:project-latest
          ports:
          - containerPort: 4200
```

Comment: Hi Harsh,I still get 502 bad gateway when I access blog.dev after the changes to the deployment and the addition of containerPort. Please suggest!

Comment: Any help is appreciated